# Ubuntu 18.10 settings bug

Tags: settings

Ubuntu works fine, when I click settings it takes me a screen where it flashes a few things on the black (like when Linux boots up and it shows everything loading) and then takes me to login screen, where I can login again but can't open settings still. Any ideas?

```
[  578.459424] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: gr: FECS falcon already acquired by gr!
[  578.459452] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
[  578.485318] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: gr: FECS falcon already acquired by gr!
[  578.485369] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
```

The text above is the text that is shown when I do it (it shows for a brief second if that affects anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

**Note**: if this doesn't fix the problem, you'll want to reinstall the nouveau video driver, or install the Nvidia driver.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I'm assuming that tapping the check mark accepts your answer as working?

Comment: @Wolfgamer478 glad it worked for you! And yes, you accepted my answer just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem with the [nouveau driver](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/). I have had the same problem on different computers with different effects. Recently I could not open the graphical interface under 18.04.

One solution is to install the proprietary NVidia driver using the graphical interface (software-properties-gtk) or in the terminal (ubuntu-drivers).

### Graphical/GUI

In the Software & Updates window (software-properties-gtk) and Additional Drivers tab, you can choose between versions of the proprietary NVidia drivers and the "X.Org X server" Nouveau driver. Take the stable NVidia driver and reboot.

### Terminal

- Press <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> if you can't log in to Graphical/GUI.
- Log in with username and password
- Enter

  ```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers install
  ```
- This should install the NVidia driver
- Reboot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with a Nvidia GTX 1060 on the 5.3.0-26 Kernel (but even earlier) and got the following errors (check with sudo journalctl -xe) :
- Error looking up permission: GDBus.E
- failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE
- Can not get _NET_WORKAREA

Neither the gnome-shell-extension `EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com` nor `unite@hardpixel.eu` was installed.
I simply installed the proprietary driver and now it seems to work.
The answer #1 is also correct, but thus far I did not disable Wayland.

I switched to another tty and stopped gdm3 (instead of remounting, but both is ok).

1. `<ctrl>+<alt>+<F2>` and login
2. $ `sudo systemctl -l status gdm3`
   (If that is your DE.)
3. $ `sudo systemctl stop gdm3`
4. $ `sudo apt update && apt-cache search --names-only nvidia-driver`
   (Pick the latest or the one that works; apt-cache doesn't need sudo rights)
5. $ `sudo apt install nvdia-driver-$yournumber`
6. For the sake of it, I re-booted, but `start` with the above systemctl command should have been enough. Check:
7. $ `sudo systemctl -l status gdm3`
8. $ `sudo dmesg| grep -iE "error|fatal"`
9. $ `sudo journalctl -xe` # type `?error` and press enter