# Stuck in TTY after install. Seemingly full functionality except for the lack of any GUI

Tags: boot, 18.04, desktop-environments, tty

I used `startx` which gave:

[update and startx output in TTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbgEv.jpg)

I am going to try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

However, I just wanted to post here to see if there's anything else I can do to make sure the re-install works. It's been a rough couple of days computer-wise.

Thank you.

*I have found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130777/how-to-remove-tty-login) which uses:

```
systemctl set default multi-user.target
systemctl start gdm
```

Would this work? To be honest I'm a bit scared to input commands that I'm not familiar with at this point. :|

**Final Update**

A simple fix! For some reason, the Nvidia drivers didn't install.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1204630/732775) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128350/ubuntu-18-10-settings-bug) said to use:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Which worked great. Now I'm in the desktop environment!

Now to restore my old settings with Deja Dup.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you install? I see 18.04 tagged, but was it 18.04 Server or 18.04 Desktop? If it was the server version, there is no GUI.

Comment: It's the desktop version.

On a side note, is the server version entirely TTY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128350/ubuntu-18-10-settings-bug/1204630#1204630) solved my problem. It says to use:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Which worked like a charm.

I also used:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Which "fixed" `startx`; however, I'm not sure if it actually did anything. Perhaps `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` is all I needed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a desktop install, then run:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Comment: Would that install drivers, and X.authority stuff?

Comment: No it does not install anything. Looks like the problem was some video/graphics drivers and your answer below got them running.

Answer (score 0):

I had a working install, but then tried to install the proprietary drivers for  my AMD GPU. That didn't quite work, so I uninstalled it again. Then I couldn't get past the TTY anymore, and none of the two other answers worked for me.

Turns out I had apparently accidentally uninstalled all desktop, GUI and display manager packages along with the AMD GPU driver ! The following fixed it:

```
sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntustudio-desktop
```